# how to detect that the dropdown list is open or not or how to track that someone has clicked on dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a peculiar question
I am developing some website and i need a condition to determine my next operation
The requriment is this how to detect that the dropdown list is open or not or how to track that someone has clicked on dropdown list ?

Comment: `$('#MyDropdown').click(function(){....`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.focus()` or `.click()` event of Jquery:

```
$("#dropdown1").focus(function(){......});

$('#dropdown1').click(function(){......});
```

Complete Example :-

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dropdown1").focus(function(){......});
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#dropdown1').click(function(){......});
});
</script>
```

As you are using Webforms(event based asp.net) not asp.net mvc then use above code the way given below :-

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%= dropdown1.ClientID %>").focus(function(){......});
 });
</script>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $("#<%= dropdown1.ClientID %>").click(function(){......});
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: i have done it but not working 
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    $("#ddlMailLocation_StateName").focus(function(){
    alert('1');
    }
        </script>

Comment: @user3567527...put it inside  $(document).ready(function () {});..and then it will work

Comment: not working <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ddlMailLocation_StateName").focus(function(){
    alert('1');
    });
    });
    </script>   

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMailLocation_StateName" Width="166px" 
             AutoPostBack="true" runat="server">
             <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
          
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: hey..you are using asp.net and posting your question in asp.net mvc tag...just see updated answer in few secs..

Comment: use $("#<%= dropdown1.ClientID %>") to get id of dropdown...as shown above..@user3567527....

Comment: this is my javascriot still on dropdown click the alert is not firing  could you kindly analyze the coode ..
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%= ddlMailLocation_StateName.ClientID %>").click(function() {
        alert('1');
    });
    });
    </script>

Comment: have you include required js files ??..@user3567527

Comment: What js file is to include ??

Comment: Thnaks partially succeded will inform you shortly

Comment: Now kindly tell me one thing. say on mouse out i want to check wether the dropdown is open or not , then how to do that ?

Comment: you can use .focusout() read it from here...http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_focusout.asp

Comment: this example is of the dic which size and position is known but a dropdown when its populated automaticlly its div how can i know ?

Comment: @user3567527...you cannot check that dropdown is open or not..what functionality do you want actually..i think my answer is more then enough for your question..

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ElementID').change(function() {

        // save a flag true or false which will tell you that your dropdown has clicked.

    });
});
```